# Efficient solution of fmincg without providing gradient?

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I'm working on multiclass logistic regression model with a large number of features (`numFeatures`>100). Using a maximum likelihood estimation-based cost function and gradient, the `fmincg` algorithm solves the problem quickly... However, I am also experimenting with a different cost function and do not have a gradient... Is there a good way to speed up the calculation process? E.g. a different algorithm or `fmincg` setting?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, this sounds like a bad idea.

Anecdotal evidence: On a similarly dimensioned (artificial) data-set I once compared the optimization of a logistic regression by gradient descent, fmincg, and downhill-simplex. Gradient descent and fmincg did a good job in under a minute, arriving at almost identical solutions. Downhill simplex thrashed around for half an hour, and reported that it was "done" without accomplishing anything useful.

So I suggest that, if at all possible, you calculate that missing gradient.

It shouldn't be difficult: Automatic-differentiation packages exist in just about every programming language.

Also note that the standard cross-entropy/maximum-likelihood cost of the logistic regression has the nice property that it is convex, making it easy to optimize. Many other cost functions (square-error for example) do not have this property.

Comment: +1 [Automatic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation), +1 convex. Which implementation of downhill-simplex did you use ? Some have a fixed initstep; and how to define `ftol` and `xtol` for sets of points is problematic.